# Update jre 6 version 24 causing ClassCircularityError

Tags: weblogic, java

I am running an applet using a jnlp file.The applet was running fine.Today I upgraded my jre to jre 6 version 24 and my application stops after putting the splash screen.I uninstalled jre and reinstalled jre 6 version 22 and its working perfectly fine.The problem is all people who use this application have Automatic update for jre which will update the jre automatically to 24 .We can't advice to disable this automatic auto update.

The client logs gave me the exception when I try to access the weblogic context using the usual security credentials.My weblogic version is 10.3

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(prop);

java.lang.ClassCircularityError: weblogic/security/acl/internal/Security
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: weblogic/security/acl/internal/Security
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:57)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:65)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.<init>(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:30)
    at weblogic.net.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:31)
    at weblogic.net.http.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:23)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPCachedJarURLConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.net.protocol.jar.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.URLUtil.checkTargetURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.protocol.ServerURL.asUnsyncStringBuffer(ServerURL.java:533)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:215)
    at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
    at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:153)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate$1.run(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:147)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:339)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7020709
I got same exception when use custom handler and try call javascript function from java applet (like new Url("javascript:myFunction()").
There was suggestion to use a different StreamClientImpl. Maybe it works, I did not check.